# VB.NET - .accdb database not saving changes

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I can't figure out why my code won't save to my .accdb database.

I am fetching data from a .accdb database file and displaying it in a DataGridView, and then allowing changes to be made to it there. (This is a stock control system.) After making changes, the user is meant to be able to send the data back so it is saved in the .accdb file.

I have looked online everywhere and tried multiple different ways of doing this. This is the way I am currently using to solve the problem, but when running the code it does not save to the .accdb file. (However, it throws up no errors.)

```
Public Class Database
Dim datatable As DataTable
Dim adapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dbCon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Dim dbRsrc As String = "Data Source =" & System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "/Resources/List.accdb"
Dim binding As BindingSource
Dim cmdBuilder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder

Private Sub Database_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbCon.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbRsrc
    dbCon.Open()
    adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM List", dbCon)
    datatable = New DataTable
    adapter.FillSchema(datatable, SchemaType.Source)
    adapter.Fill(datatable)
    binding = New BindingSource
    binding.DataSource = datatable
    dbCon.Close()
    StockTable.DataSource = binding
End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    'insert validation here
    Try
        dbCon.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbRsrc
        dbCon.Open()
        cmdBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
        adapter.Update(datatable)
        dbCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString() & " Save Unsuccessful.")
    End Try
End Sub 
End Class
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong - when I hit the 'save' button, it should connect to the database, build a SQL query to update it and then update my datatable + .accdb database, right? 
To test it, I've tried editing multiple columns and saving it, but when opening the file it still says the same values as it had before.

Any suggestions/pointers? I'm pretty newbie to VB.NET, learnt it about 3 months ago and only just starting to get fully into it.

Comment: The first thing you should do is test what value is returned when you call `Update`.  If that's not zero then there were changes to save and they were saved.  In that case, you are simply looking in the wrong place or at the wrong time for the data.  To learn how local data files are managed, i.e. where and when to look, read this: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to the user "jmcilhinney" who helped me to reach this answer. I feel highly stupid at not realising that my code was working.

I used

```
Debug.WriteLine("Update value: " & adapter.Update(datatable))
Debug.WriteLine("Connection str: " & dbProvider & dbRsrc)
```

to find that my update command worked, and that in fact the output of my database file was in the /bin/ folder. I didn't realise that it used the /bin/ folder, and was looking in the root folder with the .VB files, etc.